# How to simulate Keyboard Events in Code in not active window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

How do I use `SendWait()` to send key strokes to a window without using `SetForegroundWindow()` to make the target window active?

Here is the SendWait example on the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Comment: note duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944621/create-an-on-screen-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=40840). Basically given some handle to a window, you need to use p/invoke and call [PostMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/PostMessage.html) with the `WM_KEYDOWN` message:

```
private const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
private const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);    

public void SendKeysToWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Here's [the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645540%28VS.85%29.aspx) of Virtual Keys.