# get descriptor of window

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an On-screen Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944621/create-an-on-screen-keyboard)

I'm trying to write a virtual keyboard. Can you tell me how I can get the descriptor `hWnd` of the focused window? (It can be for Word, Excel, Skype, etc.)

I'm using `findWindow()`, but for that I must know the name of the window.

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", null);

        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tagil");
            IntPtr edithWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
            if (!edithWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, new StringBuilder("Hello World"));
        }
```

Comment: are you wanting to get the name / handle of the Foreground Window..?

Comment: yes but i think not Foreground because foreground is my Apllictation. I want to get name or handing other window

Comment: Would't it be best to work with the Windows [Accessability API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712214.aspx) to provide the extra keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this is very likely the wrong approach to writing a virtual keyboard; you'd be better off to use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) to inject the keystrokes, and let Windows/USER32 handle routing the input to the current focused window itself - this way you don't even need to know the current focused window in the first place.

One issue is that while Edit/Richedit control will use WM_SETTEXT, many other real-world editable controls - like Word, Excel and so on - don't. Also, you can't use WM_SETTEXT to send arrow keys or other non-textual content.

If you still really need to find the current focused HWND, you can use [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx), passing 0 for the idThread, and then use the hwndFocus member of the GUITHREADINFO struct that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`HWND WINAPI GetForegroundWindow(void);`

Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the user is currently working). The system assigns a slightly higher priority to the thread that creates the foreground window than it does to other threads.

`HWND WINAPI GetActiveWindow(void);`

Retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue.

One of those will probably do it.

Comment: `GetActiveWindow` is no use here since the window will reside in a different process.

Comment: GetForegroundWindow and GetActiveWindow they return Form1

Answer (score 0):

if you want a more complex example here you can look at this as well

See example on how you can do this with full source code here:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive301.html in this link empty page