# How to send a keystroke to an other process (ex a notepad)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sendmessage, sendkeys

I got a notepad which has a PID: 2860

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
using namespace std;
HWND SendIt (DWORD dwProcessID){
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    do {
         hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, NULL, NULL);
         DWORD dwPID = 0;
         GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);
         if (dwPID == dwProcessID) {
            cout<<"yay:"<<hwnd<<":pid:"<<dwPID<<endl;//debug
            PostMessage(hwnd,WM_KEYDOWN,'A',1); //send
         }
    } while (hwnd != 0);
    return hwnd; //Ignore that

}
int main()
{
    SendIt(2680); //notepad ID
    return 0;
}
```

and notepad should write `A` to it but nothing happens.
I tried `WM_DESTROY` message on it and it's working but `WM_KEYDOWN` is not working.
I have also done `GetLastError()` and it prints error 2 `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Why is this not working and is it possible to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an On-screen Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944621/create-an-on-screen-keyboard), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/how-do-i-send-key-strokes-to-a-window-without-having-to-activate-it-using-window?rq=1, and countless others.

Comment: Try using SendInput http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You are sending fake input to the notepad window, while you should be sending it to the editbox contained into it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407769/directly-sending-keystrokes-to-another-process-via-hooking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostThreadMessage should be used.

```
hThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&dwPID);  
if (dwPID == dwProcessID && hThread!= NULL ) {
   PostThreadMessage( hThread, WM_KEYDOWN,'A',1);
}
```

Two process must be created by same user. Otherwise, the function fails and returns ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID.

If the other process is active window which is capturing keyboard input, SendInput or keybd_event also can be used to send keystroke event.

Answer (score 3):

> I got a notepad which has a PID: 2860

Couldn't help noticing that you are saying 2860 and calling 2680

> SendIt(2680); //notepad ID