# Is there a way to move the cursor to the end of a text file when opened on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, text-files

I am writing to a text file using c++ and using a batch file to open the text file and then run the corresponding exe file at the same time. My c++ code is writing a dividing underscore line and the current date and then the user would write whatever text. The issue is that when I run the batch file which opens the text file, the cursor is at the beginning of the file and I want it to start at the very end so I wouldn't have to move it myself to write text.

This is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string underscoreDiv (int lengthText){

    string underscores;
    
    for(int i{}; i<lengthText; i++)
    {
        underscores += "_";
    }
    
    return underscores + "\n";
}

struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    Date()
    {
        time_t t = time(0);
        tm* now = localtime(&t);

        year = now->tm_year + 1900;
        month = now->tm_mon + 1;
        day = now->tm_mday;
    }
};

int main(){
    
    fstream fileApp("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt", ios::in | ios::app);
        
    if(fileApp.is_open()){
        
        string line;
        string underscore;
        Date date;
        int count[2]={0};

        underscore=underscoreDiv (80);
        
        fileApp.clear();
        
        fileApp<<"\n";
        fileApp<<underscore<<"\n";
        fileApp<<date.month<<"/"<<date.day<<"/"<<date.year<<" : ";

        fileApp.clear();
        
        fileApp.close();
        
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Text file not found";
    }
        
    system("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my batch file

start /b C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\notes_project_app\app_proj.exe

start C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Documents\Notes_application\Notes_app.txt

'I tried playing with the c++ code but I'm finding it hasn't been able to actually move the cursor position when the file is opened through windows. I'm having trouble trying to move the cursor to the end through the batch file. I tried doing a send key page down but I couldn't get that to work either.'

There may be some unnecessary function in the code as I'm trying to other things meanwhile.

Comment: I don't think this is related to C++. This is just a Notepad thing (presumably Notepad is the default program for you). You'd have to look at its settings, but I don't think there's a setting for that.

Comment: Even if you can assume it's Notepad (which you can't, a user may have changed it) , this has no meaning. The proper programming way is to use Win32 to create your own dialog box that *programmatically* does what you want.

Comment: In addition, if you are using a high level language already, there is no need for it to run a low level script just to open an application with an argument, or a file via its default application.

Comment: Maybe this link will help [How to send a keystroke to an other process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099957/how-to-send-a-keystroke-to-an-other-process-ex-a-notepad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm... Your question is pretty confusing... After read it several times, I think I can state these points:

Neither Windows nor a Batch file "open" a text file. A text file is open by a *text editor program* (like Windows Notepad). If I correctly understand your question, you have a C++ program that create a text file and then, *after the file was created*, open the text file with the standard text editor, **not at "the same time"**. For this reason, your batch file is wrong: if both your C++ program *and* text editor run *at the same time* (both started via `start` command), then exist the possibility that Notepad open the file *before* the C++ program have completed and closed it (not matter if the `start` command of the C++ program is placed before the `start` command of Notepad).

On the other hand, you just want to open the text file (with the standard text editor) and place the cursor at the very end of the file, right? In such a case no matter who and how created the text file! So all your explanation about your C++ code (and the C++ code itself) have *no relation* with your problem and just confuse and over-complicate the problem...

**However**, in this case the C++ code show another error: it *open the text file* via a `system` command! The batch file also open the file, so the `system` command in the C++ code is wrong and must be deleted.

I think this Batch file will solve your problem:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Run the C++ program, do *NOT* use "start" here
C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\notes_project_app\app_proj.exe

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem Start the text editor program ("open" the text file)
start C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Documents\Notes_application\Notes_app.txt

rem Wait a little
timeout /T 1

rem Send a Ctrl-End key to move cursor to end of the file
%SendKeys% "^{END}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

For further details about the method to send a key from the Batch file, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135).